How can you determine if the Service Broker is in use?
I've inherited a server where all databases have the Service Broker enabled. I suspect that only SSRS uses it. Given a database where the Service Broker is enabled, what signs indicate that it is actually being used? I know that we cannot prove that it isn't used, but I'd like to know what can prove that it is.
I have consulted the documentation, but it appears that Service Broker has multiple usages and I would have to check each one. I am hoping that a much simpler solution exists.
I have Query Store enabled on all databases and I am willing to add more monitoring if it will solve this.

I would start here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/service-broker/troubleshooting-tools?view=sql-server-ver16#service-broker-performance-objects

@JonathanFite That indicates that the only database that is using the broker is msdb... which is apparently for database mail. That makes good sense. Your comment might be a complete answer.
